# Proving a Sequence is Contractive

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to prove that for $a_1 \neq a_2$, with  $a_1, a_2 \in \Re$, $a < b < 1$; and $n \geq 3$, where $a_n = ba_{n-1} + (1-b)a_{n-2}$, that the sequence {$a_n$} is contractive.

I've looked at $a_3, a_4,$ and $a_5$, and found the simplified forms of $a_{n+1} - a_n$ and $a_n - a_{n-1}$, but I can't seem to find the next step.

This is what I have for the two simplified forms from above:

$a_{n+1}-a_n = a_n(b)+a_{n-1}(1-2b)+a_{n-2}(b-1)$

$a_n - a_{n-1} = a_{n-1}(b) + a_{n-2}(1-2b)+a_{n-3}(b-1)$

Is there a way that I'm not looking at these two that I should be considering? Or is the solution staring me right in the face? One additional thing that I'm not sure of is whether the $b$ in the problem is the $b$ that I should end up with according to the definition of a contractive sequence ($|a_{n+1}-a_n| \leq b|a_n-a_{n-1}| \forall n \geq 2, n \in N $).

Comment: $a_n - a_{n-1} = (ba_{n-1}) + (1-b)a_{n-2}) - a_{n-1} = \dotsc$

Comment: So now I have that I need to find a constant such that $|ba_n+a_{n-1}(1-b)-ba_{n-1}-a_{n-2}(1-b)| \le C |ba_{n-1}+a_{n-2}(1-b) - ba_{n-2}-a_{n-3}(1-b)|$, 
but I don't see how to find it from there.

Comment: You shouldn't replace $a_{n-1}$ in that.